# Trouble with org-export-before-processing-hook in .emacs

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

When I eval `(add-hook 'org-export-before-processing-hook #'org-update-all-dblocks)` in an emacs session, function `org-update-all-dblocks` seems to be called at the preprocessing stage of export, as expected. However, if i add the hook using the above line in *.emacs* and -- after restarting my GNU Emacs instance -- I call the LaTeX export function with `C-c C-e l o` from an org document, I get the error message "Wrong number of arguments: (0 . 0), 1" reported from the `run-hook-with-args` function. It is as if the org-export-before-processing-hook runs the hooked functions with an argument. Am I even supposed to adapt that variable? Also, how to achieve executing dynamic blocks on export, if what I attempted here is not the way?

Comment: From docstring of `org-export-before-processing-hook`: `Every function in this hook will be called with one argument: the back-end currently used, as a symbol.`. You can either check the right backend is used or just wrap this function in a lambda that takes a single argument and doesn't use it.

Comment: Thanks, I should have looked at the docstring! Shouldn't you repost your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the relevant part of docstring for `org-export-before-processing-hook`:

> Every function in this hook will be called with one argument: the
>   back-end currently used, as a symbol.

You can just wrap the function you want to use in a lambda that takes the right amount of arguments if you don't need a check whether you're using the right back-end.